# CSharp ошибка CS0019 Оператор "+" невозможно применить к операнду типа "группа методов" и "Vector2" помогите пожалуйста

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PlayerLoop;

public class Scripts : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        //if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            rb.MovePosition(rb.MovePosition + Vector2.right  * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Описание пишите как описание, а не как заголовок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы перепутали метод `MovePosition()`, который устанавливает новое положение и свойство `position`, которое возвращает текущую позицию

Вместо

> ```
> rb.MovePosition(rb.MovePosition + Vector2.right  * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime);
> ```

нужно писать

```
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.right  * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```